# how to check whether a variable contain double or empty value using java in android

Tags: java, android

how to check wheather the variable containing double value or empty

??
i am getting response from web services which i have stored in 3 different different variable say for example

var1=some double value
var2= some double value
and var 3=some double value

now how to check var1,var2 and var3 wheather they really contain double value or integer value ??? this is my question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Clarify your question and place some relevant code so It'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please add some clarification: Do you have a string and you want to know if the string contains a valid double such as 2.56? Or, do you have a list and you want to know if it has duplicates values?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Double d = 1.2;
if(Double.compare(d,Double.NaN)==0) {
  Log.i("TEST", "Double is NaN");
} else {
  Log.i("TEST", "Double is not NaN");
}
```